# Search results in custom template

Tags: templates, search

I have a custom page `resources-search.php` template which handles search results for the search form. And in my `function.php` I have the following array:

```
$YearList = array('2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013');
```

Yes, You guessed it right. Its an array of year. In my `resources-search.php` I' am using this code:

```
<select name="year" id="opt_year">
<option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Year</option>
<?php
foreach($YearList as $key => $value){
echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>'; //close your tags!!
}
 ?>
</select>
```

Its a drop-down menu from the array above. This method doesn't actually works for me. In other pages it does work but not in `resources-search.php`.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Ever tried to use `range()`? How about `range( 2000, date("Y") );`? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable as global in `resources-search.php`:

```
<?php

global $YearList;

// Rest of file...
```

May I ask why you're hardcoding the years, instead of...

```
$YearList = range( 2000, 2013 );
$YearList = range( 2000, date( 'Y' ) ); // From 2000 to current year
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you define the variable in `functions.php` doesn't mean you can access it in `resources-search.php`. You instead need to put your array as part of the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) variable and then you can access it anywhere:

### In `functions.php`

```
$GLOBALS['year_list'] = array('2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013');
```

#### In `resources-search.php`

```
foreach( $GLOBALS['year_list'] as $key => $value ) {
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>'; //close your tags!!
}
```